# Data Queue size limitation - comunication from iSeries to Java

Tags: ibm-midrange

I'm having a problem with the Data Queue object. I'm sending messages to an iSeries program (aka AS400) through a Data Queue object in Java. I can write to the iSeries and read the response but the problem is that the size of the Data Queue is defined by the size of the message that I sent previously, so, when I receive the answer, this has been truncated to the size of the request message and I loose information. How can I resolve this? Can anyone help me? I'm using JTOpen library.

Thanks

Comment: How is the data queue being created?  When I create a data queue from a command prompt (using the `CRTDTAQ` command) I have to specify a maximum entry length from 1 to 64512 bytes.  Presumably if I created a data queue of length 100 and tried to put 200 bytes in, it'd truncate.

Comment: You might also be using the `create` method on the DataQueue object.  According to [this copy of the JTOpen Javadocs I found](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/DataQueue.html), that's where you'd specify a `maxEntryLength`, if you're creating from Java.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of how it's being created, a data queue has a "maximum entry length".  This is specified on the `CRTDTAQ` command from CL or in the `create` method call if setting up the DataQueue object using JTOpen.

If you're planning to send messages of different lengths through a data queue, you need to create the data queue with a "maximum entry length" greater than or equal to your actual maximum entry length.  Otherwise you risk putting something in one end and having it be truncated when it comes out the other side.

[Here's the Javadoc](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/DataQueue.html) that shows how you can `create` a data queue from JTOpen.

Comment: The DataQueue is being created with a length of 40000, and the message that we receive in Java has no more than a 1000 characters, so it is supposed to work properly. Whatsoever, when we send a 500 character message to the iSeries the response message is truncated to a length of 500. Our solution has been to fill the message that we sent with blank spaces, so that this has the same length as the response. Although, this will not solve the problem, it's what we call  a "hammer solution"...

Comment: I see.  Are you sure that the program running on the iSeries isn't truncating the data?  If you have a way to view the data queue (such as `DBU` or you could even use the `DMPOBJ` command, though that's not the friendliest way to do it), you might want to confirm that the whole response is making it to the data queue.  You'd have to send a message from your Java program and suppress the logic to consume the response to do this.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Would you be open to consider an alternative solution? The approach we used in a similar situation was to pass the content of request/response messages through user spaces (object type USRSPC on AS/400) which don't have size limitations. Well, its ~16GB if I remember correctly... Fixed size names of the user spaces, in turn, were passed through a data queue (DTAQ) between AS/400 server and Java clients.

Comment: interesting idea.  Though the max user space size is around 16 MB, according to [IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/rzamp/rzamp.pdf).  That's still a lot better than the max data queue entry size of 64 kB.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @dmc! Its been a while, so the details are a little faded, sorry. I just remember it was much better then DTAARA, USRQ or DTAQ. Thanks again.

Comment: There are security concerns with user spaces (hence the need for the *SEC QALWUSRDMN system value). Why not just dump the file (the "message") into a shared directory and use the data queue to send the path/name? No concerns about sizes there.